# Golang equivalent of creating a subprocess in Python

Tags: python, go

I am attempting to convert a Python script to Golang, just really to see performance differences and to help me learn Golang more.

In Python, I have 2 scripts. One is a script that runs an infinite loop and sleeps for a minute before running again. The code checks an endpoint on my server and reads the output, then determines if it needs to do anything. If it does, it handles the output and starts a new subprocess. The subprocess is another Python script that does a lot of calculations and creates hundreds of threads. There can be multiple subprocesses running at any given time and they're all different tasks for different users.

I've got my Golang code reading from the API, and it's ready to start a new subprocess. But I'm not really sure how I go about it.

I know when I've created the new subprocess (or whatever it is that is the Go equivalent) I can create a bunch of Go routines, but really I'm just stuck on the "subprocess" bit.

I have tried using Go routines as a substitute for the subprocess but I don't think this is the way to go?

As requested for visualisation purposes, I have added an example of the code.

api.py:

```
while True:
    someparameter = 'randomIDfromdatabase'
    subprocess.Popen(["python3", "mycode.py", someparameter])
    time.sleep(60)
```

mycode.py

```
parameter = sys.argv[1]
for i in range(0, 100):
    thread.append(MyClass(parameter))
    thread.start()
```

I basically need the Golang equivalent of "subprocess.Popen".

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), what have written please check once `I have 2 scripts`  and `I don't have any code to show`

Comment: @Dev I mean, that's me just explaining the process I've trying to achieve with a different language. I'm not having issues with the 2 scripts I currently have, I just wanted to explain what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: to answer your question it is necessary to understand that what kind of problem or code trials you are talking about that you didn't added, otherwise it falls in too broad context

Comment: @Dev so I need to add some Python code, with a while loop and it creates a process? Okay.

Comment: Processes and "subprocesses" have nothing to do with the language you're using. These are fundamental OS concepts. Having said that, you almost certainly should not use a subprocess in Go--you should probably use a goroutine instead.

Comment: @Flimzy I added some code to show what I'm doing in Python. I was thinking a Goroutine but I didn't know if creating a Goroutine that creates 100 other Goroutines was the correct way to go about it, but if that's the correct method then I guess i'll do that!

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too. Stackoverflow is NOT a code translation service - most of us make a living of that kind of work. Furthermore, can we assume that you have read https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1 ?

Comment: What's the point of splitting this into separate processes and separate modules in Python, either?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the Go `os/exec` package for subprocess-like behavior. For example, here's a trivial program that runs the `date` program in a subprocess and reports its stdout:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("date").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

A more interesting example [from gobyexample](https://gobyexample.com/spawning-processes) that shows how to interact with the stdio/stdout of launched processes:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "io/ioutil"
import "os/exec"

func main() {

    // We'll start with a simple command that takes no
    // arguments or input and just prints something to
    // stdout. The `exec.Command` helper creates an object
    // to represent this external process.
    dateCmd := exec.Command("date")

    // `.Output` is another helper that handles the common
    // case of running a command, waiting for it to finish,
    // and collecting its output. If there were no errors,
    // `dateOut` will hold bytes with the date info.
    dateOut, err := dateCmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("> date")
    fmt.Println(string(dateOut))

    // Next we'll look at a slightly more involved case
    // where we pipe data to the external process on its
    // `stdin` and collect the results from its `stdout`.
    grepCmd := exec.Command("grep", "hello")

    // Here we explicitly grab input/output pipes, start
    // the process, write some input to it, read the
    // resulting output, and finally wait for the process
    // to exit.
    grepIn, _ := grepCmd.StdinPipe()
    grepOut, _ := grepCmd.StdoutPipe()
    grepCmd.Start()
    grepIn.Write([]byte("hello grep\ngoodbye grep"))
    grepIn.Close()
    grepBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(grepOut)
    grepCmd.Wait()

    // We ommited error checks in the above example, but
    // you could use the usual `if err != nil` pattern for
    // all of them. We also only collect the `StdoutPipe`
    // results, but you could collect the `StderrPipe` in
    // exactly the same way.
    fmt.Println("> grep hello")
    fmt.Println(string(grepBytes))

    // Note that when spawning commands we need to
    // provide an explicitly delineated command and
    // argument array, vs. being able to just pass in one
    // command-line string. If you want to spawn a full
    // command with a string, you can use `bash`'s `-c`
    // option:
    lsCmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "ls -a -l -h")
    lsOut, err := lsCmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("> ls -a -l -h")
    fmt.Println(string(lsOut))
}
```

---

Note that goroutines have little to do with subprocesses. Goroutines are a way to do multiple things concurrently *in a single Go process*. That said, when interacting with subprocesses, goroutines often come in handy because they help waiting for subprocesses to finish while also doing other things in the launching (main) program. But the details of this are very specific to your application.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/estebangarcia21/subprocess

### Sanitized mode

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/estebangarcia21/subprocess"
)

func main() {
    s := subprocess.New("ls", subprocess.Arg("-lh"))

    if err := s.Exec(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

### Shell mode

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/estebangarcia21/subprocess"
)

func main() {
    s := subprocess.New("ls -lh", subprocess.Shell)

    if err := s.Exec(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```